# Php replace string not working

Tags: php

I am trying to replace a particular string from a file but I am not able to.This is my php code:

```
<?php 

  session_start();

          $name = $_GET["Username"];
          $status = $_GET["Status"];

          $username = "jois";



          if($status == "Following"){
          $filename = $username."/contacts.txt";
         $contactList =  file_get_contents($filename);

              $object =    json_decode($contactList,TRUE);  

               $array = $object["A"];

            $str = json_encode($array);

            $new =   array('name' => 'Sumanth' );

              array_push($array,$new);

    $strArr =  json_encode($array);

            echo "str: ".$str."\n";
            echo "strArr: ".$strArr."\n";


        if( str_replace($str,   $strArr, $contactList)){
            echo    str_replace($str,   $strArr, $contactList);
        }
        else{
            echo "couldnt find the match";
        }

          }
          else{


          }


 ?>
```

This is the json present in the file:

```
  {
"A":[
{
"name": "Aaron Paul"
}

],
"B":[

{
"name":"Beyonce"
}

]

}
```

**EDIT:**

```
$str= [{"name":"Aaron Paul"}]
 $strArr= [{"name":"Aaron Paul"},{"name":"Sumanth"}]
  $contactList={ "A":[ { "name": "Aaron Paul" } ], "B":[ { "name":"Beyonce" } ] }
```

I want to replace the contents of the file . Here I am trying to replace contents in the **Array A**. and This is the above code I am trying o use to replace  contents of Array A with a new String. But I am not able to it still remains the same.I am not getting any error. Can I know where I am going wrong?

Comment: can i use the json file for the solution???

Comment: Show us the before and after of the json file with your current code, and then show us how you want the "after" to look like

Comment: @FrayneKonok Yes you can

Comment: @Webeng I am not actually changing the file contents in this code but i will edit and upload the the string values

Comment: See this: [https://3v4l.org/4feTG](https://3v4l.org/4feTG)

Comment: I did I want add new element and upload it to the file

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code from where I see it. Lets review what you are tryoing to do:

```
$str= [{"name":"Aaron Paul"}]
 $strArr= [{"name":"Aaron Paul"},{"name":"Sumanth"}]
  $contactList={ "A":[ { "name": "Aaron Paul" } ], "B":[ { "name":"Beyonce" } ] }
```

From my understanding, you want to take `$str`, search for that specific string inside `$contactList`, and then replace all instances of that string with `$strArr`. The first problem I noticed is that you did not use `str_replace()` correctly. You need to use the wildcard character: `%` to define the limits of `$str`. For example:

```
//if you had the following string:
$string = 'abcdeafg';
//and you wanted to replace all the instances
//of 'a' with 'z'
$str1 = 'a';
$str2 = 'z';
//you would then need to use '%' as follows:
$result = str_replace("%{$str1}%", "{str2}", $string);
echo $result;//output: zbcdezfg
```

So in your case, your code should look like this:

```
$result = str_replace("%{$str}%",  "{$strArr}", $contactList);
```

**HOWEVER**, you have another problem in your code. I am noticing that the string inside `$str` does not exactly match the string inside `$contactList` because you have additional spaces inside `$contactList`. So you would also have to 2 one of the following things (along with the previous code correction:

- Either somehow make sure `$contactList` has the exact same string as `$str` inside it.
- Or use `regex` with `preg_replace()` to create a more advanced search, though that is a bit more complicated and if you don't know `regex` will demand some tutorial time :).

  ---

**Edited:** I just noticed the `json_decode` being used on `$contactList`. If you place `json_decode` after the `str_replace` function and use my code, then `$contactList` will no longer have the spaces and the function should work fine :)

Comment: I am working on it Give me some time I will let you know

Comment: I really don't understand why you spent so much time explaining something which is really wrong.. `json_decode` function returns an object/array which can be easily modified. Why should I complicate the code with string replacements when I can easily use array functions?

Comment: @MateiMihai Please go throught question again

Comment: @Webeng Thankyou I used preg_replace to remove all the white spaces! and now it's working. It was whitespaces ! The Culprit thankyou

Comment: @Webeng % dint help me out

Comment: @Jois no problem dude.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more easily as:

```
$username = "jois";

if ($status == "Following") {
    $filename = $username . '/contacts.txt';

    $contacts = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);  

    $contacts['A'] = array('name' => 'Sumanth');

    file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($contacts));
}
```

If you're not sure what a function does in PHP (like `json_decode`) you can simply use `var_dump` to see what the variables contains.

Comment: Actually I want keep the old contents also ! I just want add the new element to A array with removing any elements

Comment: You want to remove or you don't want to remove the other elements of A? Right now the code simply adds a new element to the array.. as I suppose you want

Comment: @Jois did you tested the solution I gave? is there something wrong?

Comment: Yea i did I am not getting the solution ! I am sorry

Comment: and the solution is? let me know what do you expect to have in the file at the end..